# How to add another object to this object

Tags: javascript

I am new to JSON and Here is my First JSON Object

```
var First = {
              "a" : [{}]
            };
```

I want to add the below object to "a" in "First"

```
var a = {"1":"One","2":"Two"};
```

I have tried below code

```
First.a[First.a.length-1] = a;
```

It is not working.I assume that there are some syntax mistakes in this. Please help me on this.

Comment: I removed the tags `jquery` and `json`, as neither is at all relevant to this question, and added `javascript`.

Comment: Please review [json.org](http://json.org/) for a better understanding of what JSON is and how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it you want to add it, you're looking for `First.a.push(a)`
if you want to replace the last element:

```
First.a[First.a.length-1] = a;
```

if you want to append a to the last element:

```
First.a[First.a.length-1]['a'] = a;
```

or

```
  First.a[First.a.length-1].a = a;
```

if it's none of these, please add the expected json in your question.

Comment: OMG, Can we push as we push in Arrays?

Comment: @Sol, `a` is an array, so you can use `push`. `[]` is the array literal syntax, `{}` is the object literal syntax.

Comment: Is it ironic or I don't get the question? edit: ok your problem was you didn't see you were in an array :)

Comment: @Guillaume86 How to retrieve element of pushed object("a" in the above case).

Comment: actually you got the get synthax, just use the same to do the set ;)

Comment: @Guillaume86 I am sorry to buzz you again on this.. Please have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/sFPXh/3/ . I gave comments on each line what I want . I am sorry again

Comment: @Sol your alert in the fiddle is returning undefined because you initialize your "a" property of the "First" object with an empty object via [{}]. If you delete the {}, just initializing an empty array, then your alert will show "One".

Comment: no problem: http://jsfiddle.net/sFPXh/4/ , I made this one as complete as possible

Answer (score 1):

You should use Array.push().

```
var myObject = { 
    myArrayOfObjects: []
};

var newObject = { 
    1: '1',
    2: '2'
};

myObject.myArrayOfObjects.push(newObject);
```

Comment: push will do always bottom of you existing array, how to add item in top of the existing array?

Comment: use [Array.unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

Answer (score 1):

That's not a "JSON object". There isn't even any such thing. It's a Javascript object.

It's not working as you expect as you are not adding an item to the array, you are replacing the last item.

Just use the `push` method to add an item at the end of the array:

```
First.a.push(a);
```

Comment: I thought JSON object (though redundant) was the same thing as javascript object?

Comment: @jbabey: It's not. JSON is a *text format* that is mainly used to send data to (or from) Javascript client code. It can however be used in an environment where there is no Javascript involved at all.

Comment: @Guffa, I have to disagree. JSON stands for `JavaScript Object Notation`. a JSON object (an object that uses JavaScript Object Notation as defined at [json.org](http://json.org/)) uses the literal syntax: `{}`, a JSON array uses the literal syntax: `[]`. In other languages it may need to be encoded as a string, but in JavaScript, it's simply the common syntax for instantiating objects/arrays, although it can *also* be stored in a string format.

Comment: I personally think it is just a semantic difference, but I think what Guffa is trying to say is that it is not a "JSON object", but rather a javascript object that happens to contain JSON, which is a text format that provides a standard way to represent data.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Just because JSON borrows part of the syntax from Javascript doesn't mean that it *is* Javascript. If you use the syntax in Javascript code, then it's Javascript, not JSON.

Comment: @Guffa, JSONP (part of JSON) returns an executable JavaScript. [JSON is based on a subset of JavaScript](http://json.org), which means that it IS JavaScript (assuming ECMAScript 3 or 5, future versions may or may not be backwards compatible). It's important to remember that all JSON is JavaScript, but not all JavaScript is JSON.

Comment: @jbabey: It's not even a Javascript object that contains JSON, it's just a Javascript object. A Javascript object that contains JSON would for example be: `{ json: '[1,2,3]' }`.

Comment: @zzzzBov: JSONP is a way to return JSON, but it's actually not parsed as JSON but as Javascript. JSON is not Javascript because it's not a script language, it's only a textual representation of objects.

Comment: @Guffa, given your exact definition ("textual representation of objects"), `[{}]` is a textual representation of objects, which in this case is JSON. JSON doesn't *need* to be enclosed in quotes (`"`) to be JSON.

Comment: "JSON is a text format that is completely language independent" i think this solves the dispute...

Comment: @zzzzBov: No, it's not JSON. It's Javascript code. If you put it in a string, then you can call it JSON.

Comment: @Guffa, if you'd take the time to read json.org, you'd know that there's nothing that requires JSON to be within a string. Why can't it be both JS code **and** JSON?

Comment: @zzzzBov: Javascript is code. JSON is text. Any given piece of data can be Javascript and JSON, but not both at the same time. If you use it as code, it's Javascript. If you use it as text, it's JSON. In this case it's used as code, so it's Javascript, not JSON.

Comment: @Guffa, JavaScript code *is* text; your argument is invalid. Please don't take it personally. I'm not interested in continuing this debate.